# How do you easily create empty matrices javascript?

Tags: javascript

In python, you can do this:

```
[([None] * 9) for x in range(9)]
```

and you'll get this:

```
[[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
 [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]]
```

How can I do the equivalent in javascript?

Comment: @Marc B - Beat me to the punch there

Comment: You could do this shortcut in js as well if the undefined properties from new Array would enumerate ... too bad they don't :(

Comment: @Esailija They do enumerate if (a) you fill them or (b) you iterate with `for...of`.

Comment: sometimes you'd be better off not answering instead of adding negative comments to every possible stack overflow question @Marc B.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

```
var matrix = [];
for(var i=0; i<9; i++) {
    matrix[i] = new Array(9);
}
```

... or:

```
var matrix = [];
for(var i=0; i<9; i++) {
    matrix[i] = [];
    for(var j=0; j<9; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = undefined;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not empty though. just replace the inner loop with `matrix[j] = new Array(9)`

Comment: There is something vaguely unsatisfying intellectually about using two different paradigms to create an array, first a loop, then a constructor.

Comment: Sure, this works, and may be the best solution. But somehow it seems to be missing the spirit of the question, which I interpreted as being "is there some **equivalently compact and elegant** way to do this". A little bit surprised that an answer that nests two loops to fill out a 2d array would both be upvoted so heavily and also accepted.

Answer (score 120):

#### `Array.fill`

Consider using `fill`:

```
Array(9).fill().map(()=>Array(9).fill())
```

The idea here is that `fill()` will fill out the items with `undefined`, which is enough to get `map` to work on them.

You could also fill directly:

```
Array(9).fill(Array(9))
```

*(important note:* `Array(9).fill(Array(9))` *will fill each row of the array with the same array, so changing one row will change the other rows).*

Alternatives to `Array(9).fill()` include

```
Array(...Array(9))
[].push(...Array(9))
[].concat(Array(9))
Array.from(Array(9))
```

We can rewrite the solution a bit more semantically as:

```
function array9() { return Array(9).fill(); }
array9().map(array9)
```

or

```
function array(n) { return Array(n).fill(); }
array(9).map(() => array(9))
```

`Array.from` provides us with an optional second mapping argument, so we have the alternative of writing

```
Array.from(Array(9), () => Array.from(Array(9));
```

or, if you prefer

```
function array9(map) { return Array.from(Array(9), map); }
array9(array9);
```

For verbose description and examples, see Mozilla's Docs on `Array.prototype.fill()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill).

and for `Array.from()`, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

Note that neither `Array.prototype.fill()` nor `Array.from()` has support in Internet Explorer. A polyfill for IE is available at the above MDN links.

#### Partitioning

```
partition(Array(81), 9)
```

if you have a `partition` utility handy. Here's a quick recursive one:

```
function partition(a, n) {
  return a.length ? [a.splice(0, n)].concat(partition(a, n)) : [];
}
```

#### Looping

We can loop a bit more efficiently with

```
var a = [], b;
while (a.push(b = []) < 9) while (b.push(null) < 9);
```

Taking advantage of the fact that `push` returns the new array length.

Comment: Very thorough. Nice response!

Comment: Note: If you want to fill the array with a certain number, e.g. 0, you can use `var a = Array(rows).fill(Array(columns).fill(0));`. [Example](https://i.imgur.com/uZVn9cl.png)

Comment: Note that using `Array(9).fill(Array(9))` will set each row to the _same_ array, meaning changing one row will affect the other rows. See this CodePen as an example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bMxjaG?editors=0012

Comment: @givemesnacks is right... it's useless if you want to write each element afterwards with a specific x, y because they all change ...

Comment: An edit should be made, because `Array(9).fill(Array(9))` is a really dangerous piece of code..

Comment: Try to Avoid `Array(9).fill(Array(9))` ! It passes the shallow copy to each row, if changing any item inside, it will change all columns.

Comment: yup `Array(9).fill(Array(9))` is not equivalent to `Array(9).fill().map(()=>Array(9).fill())`
. Shallow copy.

Answer (score 40):

There is something about `Array.fill` I need to mention.

If you just use below method to create a 3x3 matrix.

```
Array(3).fill(Array(3).fill(0));
```

You will find that the values in the matrix is a reference.

[image]

---

### Optimized solution (prevent passing by reference):

If you want to pass by value rather than reference, you can leverage `Array.map` to create it.

```
Array(3).fill(null).map(() => Array(3).fill(0));
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

```js
// initializing depending on i,j:
var M=Array.from({length:9}, (_,i) => Array.from({length:9}, (_,j) => i+'x'+j))

// Print it:

console.table(M)
// M.forEach(r => console.log(r))
document.body.innerHTML = `<pre>${M.map(r => r.join('\t')).join('\n')}</pre>`
// JSON.stringify(M, null, 2) // bad for matrices
```

Beware that doing this below, is wrong:

```
// var M=Array(9).fill([]) // since arrays are sparse
// or Array(9).fill(Array(9).fill(0))// initialization

// M[4][4] = 1
// M[3][4] is now 1 too!
```

Because it creates the same reference of Array 9 times, so modifying an item **modifies also** items at the same index of other rows (since it's the same reference), so you need an additional call to .slice or .map on the rows to copy them (cf torazaburo's answer which fell in this trap)

*note:* It may look like this in the future, with [Number.range() proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-Number.range)

```
const M = [...Number.range(1,10)].map(i => [...Number.range(1,10)].map(j => i+'x'+j))
```

Answer (score 4):

If you **really** like one-liners and there is a use for [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) in your project (which is a great library) you can do write-only things like:

```
_.range(9).map(function(n) {
      return _.range(9).map(function(n) {
            return null;
      });
});
```

But I would go with standard for-cycle version mentioned above.

Comment: I think you're missing a paren somewhere.. jslint likes this slightly modified version _.range(16).map(function (x) { return _.range(16).map(function (y) { return null }); }); });

Comment: you don't need the inner `_.range(9).map...`, it can be replaced with `new Array(9)`

Comment: @pomber try `new Array(9).map(i=>1)` in you console

Answer (score 4):

This is an exact fix to your problem, but I would advise against initializing the matrix with a default value that represents '0' or 'undefined', as Arrays in javascript are just regular objects, so you wind up wasting effort.  **If you want to default the cells to some meaningful value, then this snippet will work well, but if you want an uninitialized matrix, don't use this version**:

```
/**
* Generates a matrix (ie: 2-D Array) with: 
* 'm' columns, 
* 'n' rows, 
* every cell defaulting to 'd';
*/
function Matrix(m, n, d){
    var mat = Array.apply(null, new Array(m)).map(
        Array.prototype.valueOf,
        Array.apply(null, new Array(n)).map(
            function() {
               return d;
            }
        )
    );
    return mat;
}
```

Usage:

```
< Matrix(3,2,'dobon');
> Array [ Array['dobon', 'dobon'], Array['dobon', 'dobon'], Array['dobon', 'dobon'] ]
```

**If you would rather just create an uninitialized 2-D Array, then this will be more efficient than unnecessarily initializing every entry**:

```
/**
* Generates a matrix (ie: 2-D Array) with: 
* 'm' columns, 
* 'n' rows, 
* every cell remains 'undefined';
*/
function Matrix(m, n){
    var mat = Array.apply(null, new Array(m)).map(
        Array.prototype.valueOf,
        new Array(n)
    );
    return mat;
}
```

Usage:

```
< Matrix(3,2);
> Array [ Array[2], Array[2], Array[2] ]
```

Comment: could you explain please what's going on  in  your code?

Answer (score 1):

The question is slightly ambiguous, since `None` can translate into either `undefined` or `null`. `null` is a better choice:

```
var a = [], b;
var i, j;
for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  for (j = 0, b = []; j < 9; j++) {
    b.push(null);
  }
  a.push(b);
}
```

If `undefined`, you can be sloppy and just don't bother, everything is `undefined` anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

Coffeescript to the rescue!

`[1..9].map -> [1..9].map -> null`

Answer (score 1):

better. that exactly will work.

```
let mx = Matrix(9, 9);

function Matrix(w, h){
    let mx = Array(w);
    for(let i of mx.keys())
        mx[i] = Array(h);
    return mx;
}
```

what was shown

```
Array(9).fill(Array(9)); // Not correctly working
```

It does not work, because all cells are fill with one array

Answer (score 1):

For a 2-d matrix I'd do the following

```
var data = Array(9 * 9).fill(0);
var index = (i,j) => 9*i + j;
//any reference to an index, eg. (3,4) can be done as follows
data[index(3,4)];
```

You can replace **9** with any generic ROWS and COLUMNS constants.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const dim1 = 9
const dim2 = 9
const init = 0
const matrix = Array.from({length:dim1}, _=>Array(dim2).fill(init))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can create an empty **1-D** array using the explicit Array constructor:

`a = new Array(9)`

To create an array of arrays, I think that you'll have to write a nested loop as Marc described.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one, no looping:

```
(Math.pow(10, 20)+'').replace((/0/g),'1').split('').map(parseFloat);
```

Fill the '20' for length, use the (optional) regexp for handy transforms and map to ensure datatype.
I added a function to the Array prototype to easily pull the parameters of 'map' into your functions.. bit risky, some people strongly oppose touching native prototypes, but it does come in handy..

```
    Array.prototype.$args = function(idx) {
        idx || (idx = 0);
        return function() {
            return arguments.length > idx ? arguments[idx] : null;
        };
    };

// Keys
(Math.pow(10, 20)+'').replace((/0/g),'1').split('').map(this.$args(1));
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

// Matrix
(Math.pow(10, 9)+'').replace((/0/g),'1').split('').map(this.$args(1)).map(this.$args(2))
```

Comment: I'm not getting this. Where is the `this` in `this.$args(1)` given as the callaback to `map` supposed to come from?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn’t have a built-in 2D array concept, but you can certainly create an array of arrays.

```
function createMatrix(row, column, isEmpty) {
        let matrix = []
        let array = []
        let rowColumn = row * column
        for (let i = 1; i <= rowColumn; i++) {
            isEmpty ?  array.push([]) :  array.push(i)

            if (i % column === 0) {
                matrix.push(array)
                array = []
            }
        }
        return matrix
    }

createMatrix(5, 3, true)
```

or

```
function createMatrix(row, column, from) {

        let [matrix, array] = [[], []],
            total = row * column

        for (let element = from || 1; element <= total; element++) {
            array.push(element)
            if (element % column === 0) {
                matrix.push(array)
                array = []
            }
        }

        return matrix
    }

createMatrix(5, 6, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function or some like that.
:)

```
function createMatrix(line, col, defaultValue = 0){ 
    return new Array(line).fill(defaultValue).map((x)=>{ return new Array(col).fill(defaultValue); return x; }); 
}
var myMatrix = createMatrix(9,9);
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to produce the desired result, as shown in the OP, without creating references:

```js
function Matrix(x,y) {
  const mtrx = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    mtrx[i] = new Array(y).fill(null);
  }
  return mtrx;
}

const matrix = Matrix(9,9);

console.log(matrix);
```

Answer (score -1):

I'll give it my shot as well

```
var c = Array;

for( var i = 0, a = c(9); i < 9; a[i] = c(9), i++ );

console.log( a.join(",") );
//",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"
```

Readable and maintainable !

Answer (score -2):

You can add functionality to an Array by extending its `prototype` object.

```
Array.prototype.nullify = function( n ) {
    n = n >>> 0;
    for( var i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
        this[ i ] = null;
    }
    return this;
};
```

Then:

```
var arr = [].nullify(9);
```

or:

```
var arr = [].nullify(9).map(function() { return [].nullify(9); });
```

Comment: @Tobo It ensures it's a non-negative and casts to an int at the same time. If n is "-1" or -1 it'll become 4294967295. It's what I'd consider incorrect behavior as an exception being thrown or an empty result being returned is how most of the standard JS functions would handle this. It should ideally be if (typeof n !== "number" || n < 0 || isNaN(n)) { throw exception or return undefined/[] here }. Also, it's generally an anti-pattern to prototype your methods into the built in JS objects. Google on that subject if interested.