# How to create an nxn matrix (array of arrays) full of zeros?

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix

I want to create an array matrix like this:

```
createMatrix(4);

// logs:
[[0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0]];
```

Currently my solution is :

```
function createMatrix (n) {
  var innerArr;
  var outerArr = [];

  for (var i=0; i<n; i++){
    innerArr = [];
    for (var j=0; j<n; j++) {
      innerArr.push(0);
    }
    outerArr.push(innerArr);
  }
}

console.log(outerArr);
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? This will iterate nxn times which is very inefficient for something very simple.

Comment: do you specifically need 0 as default value? you could just init empty array: `var arr = new Array(4)`, values are undefined by default and `arr.length === 4`

Comment: I need to explicitly make the value 4, thanks though

Comment: why don't you just do this, `var array = [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]];`

Comment: @RajdeepPaul see my edits, I need it to work dynamically for any matrix size n. I put it in a function to clarify

Comment: Don't think so... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301400/how-do-you-easily-create-empty-matrices-javascript  It's an empty array but is already iterating n times for one dimension.

Comment: @Firedrake969 thanks for the link

Answer (score 2):

With the ECMAScript 2015 function [`Array.prototype.fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill):

```
Array(row_count).fill(Array(column_count).fill(0)).map(a => a.slice())
```

Explanation:

```
// a sparse array with row_count "absent" items:
Array(row_count)
// an array with column_count members with the value 0:
                      Array(column_count).fill(0)
// an array with row_count times the identic array as value:
Array(row_count).fill(Array(column_count).fill(0))
// shallow copy the inner array:
Array(row_count).fill(Array(column_count).fill(0)).map(a => a.slice())
```

Speed?

- n=4: http://jsperf.com/creatematrix/1
- n=8: http://jsperf.com/creatematrix/2
- n=16: http://jsperf.com/creatematrix/3
- n=32: http://jsperf.com/creatematrix/4

Seemingly the `Array.prototype.fill()` variant gets faster as the matrix grows (in relation to the loops). <sub>At least in Firefox. YMMV.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of approaches you could take:

## concat()/slice()

```
var numCols = 4;
var numRows = 4;

var innerArrSrc = [];
var outerArr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
    innerArrSrc.push(0);
}

for (var j = 0; j < numRows; j++) {
    outerArr.push(innerArrSrc.concat()); // Could also use innerArrSrc.slice();
}
```

Both [`Array.prototype.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) will return a shallow copy of the source array.

## one-dimensional array

Alternatively, you could represent your matrix as an one-dimensional array rather than a multi-dimensional one and provide functions to access specific indexes based on row-column values:

```
var numRows = 4;
var numCols = 4;
var len = numRows * numCols;

var outerArr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    outerArr.push(0);
}
```

A function to access a specific index of a matrix represented this way might look like:

```
function getMatrixIndex(myMatrix, col, row, numCols) {

    var index = row * numCols + col;
    return myMatrix[index];
}
```

## Array.prototype.fill

If you want to take advantage of new ES6 features [`Array.prototype.fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) should suit your needs:

```
// Multi-dimensional
var numRows = 4;
var numCols = 4;

var outerArr = new Array(row_count).fill(new Array(column_count).fill(0)).map(a => a.slice());

// Or one-dimensional
var len = numRows * numCols;
var oneDim = new Array(row_count * column_count).fill(0);
```

## jsPerf tests

You can run [this jsPerf test](http://jsperf.com/arrays-matrix-creation/4) to see which is fastest. I've tested in:

- Firefox 42.0 32-bit on Windows NT 10.0 64-bit
- Chrome 44.0.2403.130 32-bit on Windows NT 10.0 64-bit
- Chrome 47.0.2526.73 32-bit on Windows NT 10.0 64-bit
- Android Browser 42.0 (Gecko) on Android 6.0

Comment: For `Array` you don't need the `new` keyword. It's a little easier to read, in my opinion. For the `Array.prototype.fill` variant you'll have `numRows` times the same array. See my answer. +1 for the 1-D array solution!

Comment: True, but I the question was edited slightly while I was writing my answer ;) I want to dig into @Kay's comment first and then edit my answer to better fit the updated question.

Comment: @Kay good catch on my `Array.prototype.fill` bug. I've fixed it and updated the jsPerf test as well.