# How to assert an `if` condition as truthy when an array is composed of undefined objects in Angular js

Tags: angularjs, arrays, undefined, introspection, type-assertion

I have an array named as `joinedArray`. In one case, it has the value `[undefined, undefined]`.

I have written one `if condition` like:

```
if(joinArray === undefined){
    vm.selectedFriends = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.contacts, function(contact){
        if (contact.selected)
        vm.selectedFriends.push(contact.email);
    });

    $http({
        url: 'http://192.168.2.8:7200/api/creatList',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {wData:userData, uId:vm.uid, userName:vm.uName, email:vm.selectedFriends}
    }).success(function(res) {
        console.log("success");
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        alert('here');
    });
    $mdDialog.hide(userData);
} else {
    $http({
        url: 'http://192.168.2.8:7200/api/sendMail',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {wData:userData, email:joinArray, uId:vm.uid, userName:vm.uName}
    }).success(function(res) {
        console.log("success");
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        alert('here');
    });
    $mdDialog.hide(userData);
}
```

Sometimes `joinedArray` returns like `[value, undefined]` or `[undefined, value]`. But only when both values are undefined should it pass to the `if` condition, otherwise it should go to `else` condition.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if array is empty or exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743392/check-if-array-is-empty-or-exists)

Answer (score 1):

Use Array.every...

```
var allAreUndefined = joinedArray.every(function(value) {
  return value === undefined;
});
```

To check if the array is defined you need to use typeof, as suggested in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743392/check-if-array-is-empty-or-exists).

Comment: I have edited my question how to use for that if condition.

Comment: I have used this before that if condition and I made if condition like if(joinArray === allAreUndefined) but its not working it is going to else condition.

Answer (score 0):

Use a stringified array, a regular expression replacement, and an empty string comparison. For example:

```js
    /* If a stringified array consists of null values, convert it to an empty string, and return null
    */
    if (JSON.stringify(Array(10)).replace(/^\[(null[,\]])+/,"") === "")
      {
      console.log(null);
      }
    else
      {
      console.log(NaN);
      }
```

Or more specifically:

```js
"use strict";

/* evaluate a stringified array to get the evaled values */
var foo = Function("return eval(JSON.stringify(Array(10)).replace(/null/g, undefined))")();


if (JSON.stringify(foo).replace(/^\[(null[,\]])+/,"") === "")
    {
    console.log("null");
    }
else
    {
    console.log("not null");
    }


/* 
Use foo.indexOf(null) before all this to avoid false positives
*/
```

**References**

- [Mozilla Bug 1250191 - Add a way to serialize JSON canonically](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1250191)
- [How do you easily create empty matrices javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301400/113772)
- [Power up the array creation in JavaScript](https://rainsoft.io/power-up-the-array-creation-in-javascript/)
- [Why does Array.apply(null, [args]) act inconsistently when dealing with sparse arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22949976/1113772)
- [Speaking JavaScript, Chapter 18. Arrays](http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch18.html)