# Matrix transpose JS

Tags: javascript, matrix, transpose

Functions that output the transpose of a matrix - a new matrix where the columns and rows of the original are swapped. I'm trying to figure out **why the second function outputs incorrect results?**

```
function transpose(matrix) {
    let res = [];
    for(let i = 0;  i < matrix[0].length; i++) {
        res[i] = [];
        for(let j = 0;  j < matrix.length; j++) {
            res[i][j] = matrix[j][i];
        }
    }
    return res; 
}

function transpose(matrix) {
    let res = Array(matrix[0].length).fill([]);
    for(let i = 0;  i < res.length; i++) {
        for(let j = 0;  j < matrix.length; j++) {
            res[i][j] = matrix[j][i];
        }
    }
    return res; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the second function fails because of the `let res` line. When you use `.fill([])`, you are filling with the same array as [givemesnacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301400/how-do-you-easily-create-empty-matrices-javascript#comment87738391_33079812) mentions in this comment

If you do `console.log(transpose([[1, 2, 3], [7, 4, 3]]))`, you'll notice that the elements in the array are the same.

To fix this, you can try `let res = Array(matrix[0].length).fill().map(() => []);`, which should add a new empty array for every row.

```js
function transpose(matrix) {
  let res = Array(matrix[0].length).fill().map(() => []);
  for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
      res[i][j] = matrix[j][i];
    }
  }
  return res;
}

let m = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8]
]

console.log(transpose(m))
```